# How do I filter multi-level columns using notnull() in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I generate a multi-index dataframe that has some NAN values using this:

```
arrays = [["bar", "bar", "baz", "baz", "foo", "foo", "qux", "qux"],["one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two"],]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
a = np.random.randn(3, 8)
mask = np.random.choice([1, 0], a.shape, p=[.3, .7]).astype(bool)
a[mask] = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=index)
df
```

Which will create something like this:

[image]

I'd like to get rows of a specific subset of top-level columns (eg `df[['baz','qux']]`) that have no nulls. For example in `df[['baz','qux']]` I'd like to get rows 0 and 1 since they both have all nulls in 3.

Hoping things would just work like a normal df I tried:

```
cols = ['bar','baz']
df[cols].loc[df[cols].notnull()]
```

But I obviously am missing something:

```
ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

The pandas documentation for [multiindex/advanced indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html) illustrates how to index and slic this sort of dataframe but doesn't seem to have anything regarding .loc/lookups/filtering. So I assume I'm looking in the wrong place. But I am having trouble finding results or resources on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df[cols].notna()` is not a 1D boolean mask. You have to reduce the dimension using `all` or `any` on axis.

```
>>> df[df[cols].notna().all(1)]

        bar                 baz                 foo                 qux
        one       two       one       two       one       two       one       two
0  1.799680 -0.901705 -1.575930  0.185863 -0.793007  1.485423       NaN       NaN
2  1.379878 -0.748599  0.661697 -1.015311 -0.858144       NaN -1.623013  0.340043
```

Comment: For my specific need I used any. Thanks! `df[df[cols].notnull().any(1)]`